# Ссылки на константу и продление жизни временных объектов в С++

Tags: c++

Изучаю perfect forwarding + move semantic и решил подробнее сформулировать для себя некоторые моменты работы ссылок в C++. Они так или иначе касаются константных ссылок на временные объекты. Нужен контроль, что я правильно усвоил эти моменты.

```
int main( )
{
    const int& ref = 1;      
    cout << ref << endl;    // ок
}
```

Таким образом, время жизни rvalue продлевается до конца времени жизни `ref`, т.е. до конца функции `main( )`. Соответственно, если передать `ref` как параметр в к-л функцию, все будет работать корректно.

```
void foo(int& arg);
foo(ref);                   // ок
```

Аргумент arg просто копирует значение ссылки `ref`, которая продолжает жить.

Если же, наоборот, использовать возврат из функции по ссылке на константу на временный объект внутри самой функции, получится висячая ссылка.

```
const int& foo( )
{
    const int& i = 1;
    return i;
}

const int& ref = foo( );    // ошибка
```

Здесь снова все логично, т.к. значение ссылки `i` при возврате из функции копируется в `ref`, а сама `i` уничтожается. Следовательно, 'уничтожается' и '1'. Вообще-то, возможна ситуация, при которой она лежала в стеке и еще может существовать по адресу в памяти, на который ссылается `ref`. Но до тех пор, пока не будет затерта данными нового фрейма стека. Возвращаясь к предыдущему примеру:

```
const int& ref = foo( );       
cout << ref << endl;        // ошибка (хотя может повезти с правильным значением)

const int& ref = foo( );    
boo( );                     // затирается фрейм, который создавался foo( )  
cout << ref << endl;        // ошибка (совсем ошибка)
```

В то же время, если использовать возврат по значению, то вполне можно проинициализировать им ссылку на константу:

```
int foo( ) { return 1; }
const int& ref = foo( );    // ок
```

Кроме того, базовое правило для временного объекта гласит, что уничтожение временного объекта это последний шаг вычисления full-expression, внутри которого этот временный объект был создан. Следовательно, при возврате по значению можно не только проинициализировать им ссылку на константу, но и использовать тут же, в пределах full-expression:

```
void print(const int& arg)
{ 
    cout << arg << endl;  
}

int foo( ) 
{ 
    return 1; 
}  

print(foo( ));              // ок
```

Правильно ли, что место всегда выделяется на стеке?
Есть ли еще критически важные нюансы?

Прошу прокомментировать / поправить / дополнить.
Заранее благодарен всем, кто внесет свою лепту!

*** UPDATE ***

Благодарность [KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2739/kovadim), который помог разобраться с отличием продления жизни временного объекта и возвратом значения из функции по ссылке на константу:

Последний пример = продление жизни временного объекта, т.к. именно такое временное значение возвращается из `foo( )` и тут же присваивается аргументу `print( )` - стандарт, §6.7.7, 5-6 (6.9)

Но если `foo( )` возвращает `const int&`, то даже сразу вызвать `print(foo( ));` будет ошибкой, поскольку 'манипуляции орудуют с трупиком'

*** UPDATE 2 ***

Благодарность [user7860670](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/272035/user7860670) за указание на то, что размещение переменных с автоматическим временем хранения зависит от компилятора.

> На системах с аппаратным стеком такие действительно часто размещаются
> на стеке. Однако они могут размещаться и в регистрах (особенно если не
> брать адрес), а константы могут запросто попадать и в блок статических
> данных или даже встраиваться в машинный код.

Comment: В самом первом примере уже не ок. Нельзя присвоить новое значение константе.

Comment: Продление жизни временному объекту через локальную ссылку всегда является грубой ошибкой. *"Очевидно, память под '1' выделяется на стеке."* - это ни разу не очевидно.

Comment: если у автора вопроса "константные ссылки", тогда значение в теории можно было бы поменять, но у него там "ссылка на константу". Да, я знаю, все говорят константная ссылка, но это немного неверно. и последний пример тоже не ок.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ  ... Глупость знатную я написал. Исправил

Comment: @KoVadim , Вы правы. Думаю, будет полезно говорить точно. Так что сейчас поправлю все вопросе. А насчет последнего примера поясните, пожалуйста, что с ним не так?

Comment: Вы возвращаете ссылку на локальный объект (объект на стеке). Все. дальнейшие Ваши манипуляции уже орудуют с трупиком. Неважно как. Вы путаете это с продлением жизни временного объекта.

Comment: @KoVadim , вчитался еще раз в стандарт. Нашел место, которое я неправильно интерпретировал. Спасибо, Вы очень помогли

Comment: @user7860670 , а где выделяется эта память? Если написать `const int& ref = 1;` и затем  `cout << &ref << endl;` получим адрес на стеке. https://godbolt.org/z/T81EdcxYo

Comment: Это переменная с автоматическим временем хранения. Она размещается на усмотрение компилятора. На системах с аппаратным стеком такие действительно часто размещаются на стеке. Одна они могут размещаться и в регистрах (особенно если не брать адрес), а константы могут запросто попадать и в блок статических данных или даже встраиваться в машинный код.

Comment: @user7860670 , под константами, который могут запросто попасть в блок статических данных Вы имеете в виду строковые константы?

Comment: Нет, я имею ввиду любые константные объекты.

Comment: @user7860670 , спасибо за пояснение за стек, регистры, статические данные и машинный код. Очень полезно.